# Getting one result of each id, but only the one with the newest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a system that stores documents in a database, each user can create multiple documents and each document is saved in different versions. Each user has a unique token. Each document has a unique id. Each document is being stored many times but at different times.

Example of my table:

```
|AI  |token |docid   time|
|1   |id1   |doc1    1000|
|2   |id2   |doc2    1001|
|3   |id1   |doc1    909 |
|4   |id2   |doc1    1020|
|5   |id1   |doc3    801 |
```

What I need is a query that gives me only the newest of each document for a particular user.

So in this example I would like for user with token `id1`:

```
1   id1   doc1    1000
5   id1   doc3    801
```

How would a query that achieve this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query:

```
select token, docid, max(time) time
from tablename
group by token, docid
```

you get the newest `time` for each `token` and `docid`.
If you don't need the `AI` column then you're done.
If you also need the `AI` column you must join this query to the table:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t inner join (
  select token, docid, max(time) time
  from tablename
  group by token, docid
) g on g.token = t.token and g.docid = t.docid and g.time = t.time
```

If you want results only for token = 'id1', you can add a condition:

```
where t.token = 'id1'
```

or you can also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
where 
  t.token = 'id1'
  and not exists (
    select 1 from tablename
    where token = t.token and docid = t.docid and time > t.time
  );
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m98e5MERQmgngtJt7voYyT/1).
Results:

```
| ai  | token | docid | time |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ---- |
| 1   | id1   | doc1  | 1000 |
| 5   | id1   | doc3  | 801  |
```

Comment: Don't forget filtering on user `token`.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks. I completely missed that part.

Comment: Sorry man - i'm getting the correct rows, BUT and this i completely realize i should have added to my question is that i also need more row data. I have another column called filename and i also need that. It shouldn't sort or do anything with the filename column i just need it to be part of the result. I thought (due to my inexperience with sql that i could add that column name at the end of the list) -> but then it messes up the results. Could i ask you, how the command should be if i also want that column to be part of the result?

Comment: Also i'm really not experienced in sql at all -> all these command that contain stuff like "t.*" or t.docid , don't return anything on my system. I'm on mySql 4.6.1, maybe that has anything to do with it. It's the version that came with my web service so i can't upgrade.

Comment: With `t.*` you get **all the columns** of the table aliased as `t`. In this case `t` is your table's name. I don't understand why you don't get all the columns. I can only test the code in MYSql 5.7+.

Comment: @forpas ok, once again my inexperience was at fault - all works :D getting the entre row data. Thanks for your time and help :D

Comment: Fine if it works.